# Which one is correct "runs in" or "runs on"?

Tags: prepositions

Which one is correct:

> The client part was also implemented in Python which **runs on** a web browser with the help of the Brython translator.

or,

> The client part was also implemented in Python which **runs in** a web browser with the help of the Brython translator.

?

Comment: Apparently both expressions are correct, with “runs in” as the more commonly used. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=runs+on+a+web+browser%2Cruns+in+a+web+browser&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cruns%20on%20a%20web%20browser%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cruns%20in%20a%20web%20browser%3B%2Cc0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, "in" sounds more natural when talking about a web browser. A browser is conceived of as a place you inhabit while consuming web content. However, "on" can be used to emphasize the *platform* for software (e.g., "it runs on Windows"). In this case, the browser serves as the platform for code. So both sentences sound OK.

Answer (score 1):

Generally **on** is used to describe the hardware on which a program runs:

> The program is written in Java, and as such it can be run **on** Windows PCs, Macs, and *nix machines.

**In** is used to describe where exactly the program runs, in the context of a single machine:

> The script is executed **in** userspace.
> JavaScript runs **in** a specific browser tab.

(The line can get a little blurred in the context of a *virtual machine*, which is a piece of software which emulates an entirely different piece of hardware; I think saying "the program is running **in/on** a virtual machine" would both be idiomatic.)

In your case I would say that the Python program runs **in** a browser window, if it is the case that closing the browser window will terminate the Python program—that is, it is not being executed as its own distinct process, but only as a child process of the browser program.

Comment: I hate to be pedantic, but "Windows, Mac, and Linux" are operating systems, (software) not hardware. If you meant operating system, you could say "The program is written in Java which runs **under** Windows, Mac, and Linux" . Or if you really meant hardware then " .... which runs **on** PCs, Apple MacBooks and IBM AIX machines"

Comment: @Peter: no need to apologize, I'm an incorrigible pedant myself. Edited.